# Python MySQL Connector: Why do I get different error messages depending on user for the same error?

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling, mysql-connector-python

I am connecting to a mysql database to get some data. It works fine, but I am trying to build in error checking in the event something goes wrong.

Here is the test code (without error checking):

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
         user='pool',
         password='password',
         host='127.0.0.1',
         database='emsdb')
conn.close()
```

When I change the user to an incorrect user, I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'pooll'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Which is what I expected. Same when I feed it the wrong host:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'haarp:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)
```

But when I intentionally feed it the wrong database name I am getting this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'pool'@'%' to database 'emsdbb'
```

instead of this error (which I see correctly but only when using the root user):

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'emsdbb'
```

So my questions is why would the 'pool' user get a different error than the 'root' user for the exact same error (ie - wrong database)?

I want the actual, correct error to be returned, but I don't want to use the 'root' user to make that happen.

Thanks

Comment: I've removed my answer, but feel free to incorporate what you learned from it into your question.

Comment: I don't suppose you figure out why this happens, did you?

Comment: It had to do with the fact that the user I was using did not have access to any other database. The error worked fine for the 'root' user because that user can read all databases but the legit user 'pool' cannot use any db but one specific db so when I intentionally fed it the wrong db it just kicks out an 'Access denied' instead of the less cryptic 'Unknown database'. The access denied error goes away when I expand my user 'pool' to all databases which I did just as a test. So basically 'pool' had no access to anything but the one valid db - it could not check to see if emsdbb was valid.